# Zend_Form_Element_File not working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

The following Zend Framework form isn't working properly:

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Auth extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {   
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $username = $this->createElement('text','username');
        $username->setLabel('Username:')
                 ->setAttrib('size',10);

        $password = $this->createElement('password','password');
        $password->setLabel('Password')
                 ->setAttrib('size',10);

        $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
        $file->setLabel('File')
             ->setDestination('/data/uploads')
             ->setRequired(true);

        $reg = $this->createElement('submit','submit');
        $reg->setLabel('save');             

        $this->addElements(array(
            $username,
            $password,
            $file,
            $reg
        ));

        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

The problem resides in:

```
->setDestination('/data/uploads')
```

When I remove this line from the code the form is working properly. I have the upload folder in `/data/uploads` and have permission set to `777` for the directory. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Is the `data` folder really located at the root of the server or is it in your application directory?  I think you may be specifying the path wrong.  Try `APPLICATION_PATH . '/data/uploads'` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use any domain (With out localhost). if it is yes you should use data/uploads. The data directory should locate in public directory. If you have any domain you should use destination path with baseUrl.